# How to receive insets without set windowTranslucentStatus nor windowTranslucentNavigation

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have to save the default color of status bar and navigation bar. I don't need it to be transparent.

And I need to receive insets by onApplyWindowInset in my custom view.

But to receive it I have to set windowTranslucentStatus or windowTranslucentNavigation and as result I got transparent status bar or navigation bar.

How can I process insets without windowTranslucentStatus/Navigation?